# How to keep a moving sprite centralized on the screen?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a side-scroller game that includes a panning "camera" and a moving sprite. The panning "camera" is an effect created by the obstacles moving in the opposite direction of the main sprite. The problem with this is that the sprite isn't in one position; it constantly moves across the screen eventually leaving the field of view. **I want the sprite to appear to be moving but in actuality it is set in one position so it won't move out of view off the screen.**

Code for the Moving Sprite :

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(positionX - small, positionY - large);
ctx.lineTo(positionX + small, positionY - large);
ctx.lineTo(positionX + small, positionY);
ctx.lineTo(positionX - small, positionY);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

The small variable is equal to 10 and the large variable is equal to 20. These variables are here because the size of our sprite changes over time.

Code for the "Camera" :

```
function drawSquare1() {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(250 - positionX, 145, 30, 30);
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
}
```

These lines of code create a moving obstacle in our game. 
The specific line:
`ctx.rect(250 - positionX, 145, 30, 30`creates the moving "camera" illusion.

All the Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="2000" height="2000"></canvas>

<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var positionX = 50.0;
  var positionY = 175.0;
  var velocityX = 2;
  var velocityY = 0.0;
  var gravity = 0.5;
  var onGround = false;
  var deaths = 0;
  var points = 0;
  var color = "#DCD93C";
  var change1 = 175;

  //circle 1
  var point1x1 = 339;
  var point1x2 = 372;
  var point1y1 = 90;
  var point1y2 = 150;
  var circlex1 = 350;
  var circley1 = 100;

  //circle 2
  var point2x1 = 565;
  var point2x2 = 590;
  var point2y1 = 90;
  var point2y2 = 150;
  var circlex2 = 575;
  var circley2 = 100;

  //circle 3
  var point3x1 = 855;
  var point3x2 = 880;
  var point3y1 = 20;
  var point3y2 = 50;
  var circlex3 = 865;
  var circley3 = 35;

  //square size change
  small = 10;
  large = 20;



  window.addEventListener("mousedown", StartJump, false);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", EndJump, false);

  Loop();

  function StartJump() {
    if (onGround) {
      velocityY = -12.0;
      onGround = false;
    }
  }

  function EndJump() {
    if (velocityY < -6.0)
      velocityY = -6.0;
  }

  function Loop() {
    Update();
    Render();
    window.setTimeout(Loop, 30);
  }

  function Update() {
    velocityY += gravity;
    positionY += velocityY;
    positionX += velocityX;

    // Collision Detection //
    if ((positionX > (239 - positionX) && positionX < (292 - positionX) && positionY > 145) || (positionX > (439 - positionX) && positionX < (492 - positionX) && positionY > 145) || (positionX > (639 - positionX) && positionX < (692 - positionX) && positionY > 145) || (positionX > (839 - positionX) && positionX < (892 - positionX) && positionY > 145) || (positionX > (839 - positionX) && positionX < (892 - positionX) && positionY > 50 && positionY < 100) || (positionX > (1039 - positionX) && positionX < (1700 - positionX) && positionY > 166 && positionY < 176)) {
      positionY = 175;
      positionX = 50;
      deaths++;
      points = 0;

      small = 10;
      large = 20;

// circle 1

      circlex1 = 350;
      circley1 = 100;
      point1x1 = 339;
      point1x2 = 372;
      point1y1 = 90;
      point1y2 = 150;

//circle 2

      circlex2 = 575;
      circley2 = 100;
      point2x1 = 565;
      point2x2 = 595;
      point2y1 = 90;
      point2y2 = 150;

//circle 3

      point3x1 = 855;
      point3x2 = 880;
      point3y1 = 20;
      point3y2 = 50;
      circlex3 = 865;
      circley3 = 35;

    }

    if (positionY > change1) {
      positionY = change1;
      velocityY = 0.0;
      onGround = true;
    }

// End World
    if (positionX < 0 || positionX > 2000)
      velocityX *= -1;

// Platform 1
if (positionX > (1039 - positionX) && positionX < (1300 - positionX) && positionY > 101 && positionY < 111)
    {
    change1 = 111;
  }

  if (positionX > (1300 - positionX))
  {
    change1 = 175;
  }

  //Platform 2
if (positionX > (1439 - positionX) && positionX < (1510 - positionX) && positionY > 81 && positionY < 101)
    {
    change1 = 91;
  }

  if (positionX > (1510 - positionX))
  {
    change1 = 175;
  }

//Platform 3
if (positionX > (1600 - positionX) && positionX < (1750 - positionX) && positionY > 111 && positionY < 131)
    {
    change1 = 121;
  }

  if (positionX > (1750 - positionX))
  {
    change1 = 175;
  }


// Point 1
    if (positionX > (point1x1 - positionX) && positionX < (point1x2 - positionX) && positionY > point1y1 && positionY < point1y2) {
      points++;
      circlex1 = -10;
      circley1 = -10;
      point1x1 = -10;
      point1x2 = -10;
      point1y1 = -10;
      point1y2 = -10;
      small += -2;
      large = small * 2;

    }




// Point 2
    if (positionX > (point2x1 - positionX) && positionX < (point2x2 - positionX) && positionY > point2y1 && positionY < point2y2) {
      points++;
      circlex2 = -10;
      circley2 = -10;
      point2x1 = -10;
      point2x2 = -10;
      point2y1 = -10;
      point2y2 = -10;
      small += -2;
      large = small * 2;
    }

// Point 3
    if (positionX > (point3x1 - positionX) && positionX < (point3x2 - positionX) && positionY > point3y1 && positionY < point3y2) {
      points++;
      circlex3 = -10;
      circley3 = -10;
      point3x1 = -10;
      point3x2 = -10;
      point3y1 = -10;
      point3y2 = -10;
      small += -2;
      large = small * 2;
    }

// Gets Bigger One   
    if (positionX > (point1x1 - positionX) && positionX < (point1x2 - positionX) && positionY > 150) {
      small += .2;
      large = small * 2;
    }

// Gets Bigger Two
           if (positionX > (point2x1 - positionX) && positionX < (point2x2 - positionX) && positionY > 150) {
      small += .2;
      large = small * 2;
    }

// Gets Bigger Three
           if (positionX > (839 - positionX) && positionX < (892 - positionX) && positionY > 101 && positionY < 149) {
      small += .2;
      large = small * 2;
    }



  }


    function drawPlatform1() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(1050 - positionX, 111, 250, 10);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0066FF";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawPlatform2() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(1450 - positionX, 91, 60, 10);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0066FF";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  } 

  function drawPlatform3() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(1600 - positionX, 121, 150, 10);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0066FF";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawSquare1() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(250 - positionX, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawCircle1() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circlex1 - positionX, circley1, 7, 7, 500);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawCircle2() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circlex2 - positionX, circley2, 7, 7, 500);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawCircle3() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circlex3 - positionX, circley3, 7, 7, 500);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }


  function drawSquare2() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(450 - positionX, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawSquare3() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(650 - positionX, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawSquare5() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(850 - positionX, 145, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawSquare6() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(1050 - positionX, 165, 700, 10);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawSquare4() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(850 - positionX, 50, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function drawDeaths() {
    ctx.font = "16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fillText("Deaths: " + deaths, 10, 20);
  }

  function drawPoints() {
    ctx.font = "16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fillText("Points: " + points, 10, 50);
  }

  function Render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
    drawPlatform1();
    drawPlatform2();
    drawPlatform3();
    drawCircle1();
    drawCircle2();
    drawCircle3();
    drawSquare1();
    drawSquare2();
    drawSquare3();
    drawSquare4();
    drawSquare5();
    drawSquare6();

    drawDeaths();
    drawPoints();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 175);
    ctx.lineTo(2000, 175);
    ctx.stroke();



    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(positionX - small, positionY - large);
    ctx.lineTo(positionX + small, positionY - large);
    ctx.lineTo(positionX + small, positionY);
    ctx.lineTo(positionX - small, positionY);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Link to game](https://jsfiddle.net/mittank1701/b6jgo5fx/)

Comment: @DarkBee I restated my question and went into more detail because I assumed that was the problem with my other question?

Comment: You should delete your other question then... It would have been better to refactor the original instead of make a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a space ship

```
ship = {
   x : 100,
   y : 200,
}
```

and you move it through the playfield

```
ship.move = function(){
   this.x += 2;
}
```

and you have some objects placed randomly on a big playfield 10,000 pixels or more in size

```
var objects = [];
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
     objects.push(obj = {
         x: Math.random() * 10000;
         y: Math.random() * ctx.canvas.height;
     });
```

That you just draw where they are

```
     obj.draw = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(objectImage,this.x,this.y);
     }

}
```

You can set up a view by creating a transform that keeps the ship in the center.

So in your update / mainloop at the start move the ship

```
function update(){  // the update function called once a frame
    // clear the screen
    ship.move(); // move the ship
```

Then set the current transform so that its is half the canvas width and height up and left of the ship.

```
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,ship.x - ctx.canvas.width/2,ship.y - ctx.canvas.height/2);
```

draw the ship,

```
ctx.drawImage(shipImage,ship.x,ship.y)
```

and draw the objects

```
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
     objects[i].draw();
}
```

Now everything you draw will be relative to the ship. If you have an obstacle at coord 10000 and the ship is only at 100 then you will not see the obstacle, not until the ship has moved near it.

If you do it that way then you can just draw everything where it has to be and you don't have to worry about moving everything to the ship. The transform moves everything for you.

If you want the ship at a different position on the screen then just change the offset from the ship to the top left corner of the canvas.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!